# Count values for the same ID

Tags: powershell

I'm new with Powershell and I'm trying to automate a tedious task I usually do and would really appreciate it if you would be able to assist me or give any idea on how to accomplish my goal.

Basically I have a CSV file that looks something like this:

```
Name   | Message | Date     | Time 
------ | ------  | ------   | -----
John   | Good    | 1/1/2001 | 1:00 PM
John   | Bad     | 1/2/2002 | 2:00 AM
Frank  | Better  | 1/3/2003 | 3:00 PM
Frank  | Best    | 1/4/2004 | 4:00 AM
Mike   | Great   | 1/5/2005 | 5:00 PM
Mike   | Perfect | 1/6/2006 | 6:00 AM
Mike   | Awesome | 1/7/2007 | 7:00 PM
```

The output that I'm trying to achieve will look something like this:

```
Name   | Message_Count
------ | ------
John   | 2  
Frank  | 2 
Mike   | 3
```

So far, I can only remove the duplicates but I can't figure out how to count the messages on their corresponding names.

Comment: I've edited my question. I forgot to include that my data has other columns in it.

Answer (score 2):

This code can help you.

```
Import-Csv <CSV File> | 
Group-Object Name | 
Select-Object @{Name='Name'; Expression={$_.Values[0]}}, 
              @{Name='Message_Count'; Expression={$_.Count}}
```

Comment: Thank you for help. The output that I got is just the total number of Message_Count for all Names, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Below Snippet also gives the same result

```
import-csv 'Input Path' | Group-Object Name | Select-Object Name,count
```

Comment: Thank you! :) I'm gonna test this one out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the input file is exactly how you've presented it, then we need to do some work to put it in a format that PowerShell can recognize as CSV. I've adapted mfatih's code to do that:

```
Get-Content file.txt |
    % { $_ -replace "\s*\|\s*","|" } |  # Get rid of the spaces around the fields
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '|' |    # Use "|" as the delimiter.
    ? Name -notmatch '^-+$' |           # Skip the "------" row.
    Group-Object Name | 
    Select-Object @{Name='Name'; Expression={$_.Values[0]}}, 
                  @{Name='Message_Count'; Expression={$_.Count}}
```

Output:

```
Name  Message_Count
----  -------------
John              2
Frank             2
Mike              3
```

Comment: Thank you! :) I'm gonna test this one out.